# Error in FD-preserving trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, functional-dependencies, database-trigger

Consider R(A,B,C) with functional dependency B->C.
I wrote the following trigger to preserve the FD.

```
create trigger t1 on R after insert
as
if exists(select B from R
group by B 
having count(distinct C)>1 
)
print 'B->C FD does not permit!'
rollback;
```

It works fine but issues an error:

> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

How can I catch/resolve this error?

Comment: what exactly would you want to do when you are rolling back the transaction ?

Comment: Nothing but printing the message: 'B->C FD does not permit!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 on R
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT B 
        FROM (
        SELECT B, C 
        FROM R 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT B, C 
        FROM INSERTED) AS T 
        GROUP BY B 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C) > 1
    )
    PRINT 'B->C FD does not permit!'
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO R SELECT * FROM inserted
END;
GO
```

Another way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 on R
AFTER INSERT
AS
        IF EXISTS(
            SELECT B 
            FROM (
            SELECT B, C 
            FROM R 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT B, C 
            FROM INSERTED) AS T 
            GROUP BY B 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C) > 1
        )
BEGIN
PRINT 'B->C FD does not permit!'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, but AFTER the insert the FD may be corrupted, not before that!

Comment: Then add inserted in your EXISTS statement. I have changed my post. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks again, it works, but I wondered what's wrong in MY code (which is obviously more readable)? What's the meaning of that error? and is there a simple way to cache it?

Comment: If my answer helps you, please mark it as accepted or upvote it. What's wrong with your code - you need to begin try, insert data than, check some statement, then rollback or commit transaction. Error say by itself - transaction ends here, nothing to commit. Using instead of trigger is the simpliest way.

Comment: Thanks gofr, I understood.

Comment: My pleasure! Please, try second query, it must work now.

Answer (score 0):

The query in your trigger is unrelated to what you have inserted that is to `inserted` table.

```
create trigger t1 on R after insert
as
if exists(select B from R
where B  in (select B from inserted) --"is" was mistype
group by B 
having count( C)>1 --distinct allows to insert same (B,C) pairs
)
begin
print 'B->C FD does not permit!'
rollback;
end

-- insert fresh data 
insert R (A,B,C)
values
(1,'ab','cd'),
(2,'cd','ef')
--passed
-- insert more
insert R (A,B,C)
values
(3,'abc','cd'),
(4,'cde','ef'),
(5,'ab','qq')
-- failed with message:
B->C FD does not permit!
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
-- As Expected
```